# mod rewrite troubles

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to use modrewrite to give me clean urls like:

`http://www.mydomain.com/about/`

to be:

`http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?page=about`

And to go three layers in. I wrote this but its not working at all:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?section=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?section=$1&subsection=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

I tested by adding print_r($_GET); and its empty when I go to

mydomain.com/about/

Edit, got it working. Stupid me i didnt need the "/" above before index.php.

However, now it will not show me my css/images. I added this but its still not working.

```
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]
```

What it is doing is appending the url parameters onto the image requests as such:

/page/images/bg.jpg

rather than:

/images/bg.jpg

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your existing with this:

```
# If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
# If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
# If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l 
# don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&subsection=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: No dice. I can access the root / just fine. Anything added to it gives me a 404

Comment: Still no. What it is doing is appending the url parameters onto the image requests as such:

/page/images/bg.jpg

rather than:

/images/bg.jpg.

Can see for yourself at: 
http://192.168.1.147/bar/

vs

http://192.168.1.147/bar/foo/

Comment: That means code is now working fine. Now `192.168.1.147` is your **intranet** IP and I can't access that. Secondly make sure your images, css & js files etc have absolute URL which means either they start with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: Yes I'm an idiot i gave you the wrong ip. Lmao. Here:

68.5 5.111.180

I tired setting my paths to absolute (check the source please). still not loading them :(

Comment: I tired setting my paths to absolute "/stylesheet/style.css" instead of "stylesheet/style.css". Doing that it breaks when i go to the root AND when I go to a page.

Comment: I browsed to `http://68.55.111.180/bar` and some of the sub pages linked on that page and was able to get pictures on every one of them. Though I see a PHP notice on top `Notice: Undefined index: page in /var/www/bar/index.php on line 4 Notice: Undefined index: section in /var/www/bar/index.php on line 5`